# Android - Resize image automatically

Tags: android

I have created one image in ms-paint and moved that to my drawable folder.
Now I want that it should resize automatically depending upon device or screen orientation.

Also, I am using this image inside TextView and using below code for that:

```
text.setText(Html.fromHtml(content, new ImageGetter() {
    @Override
    public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
        Drawable drawFromPath;
        int path = getActivity().getResources().getIdentifier(
                source, "drawable",
                "com.ssand.app.edu.finaccouting");
        drawFromPath = (Drawable) getActivity().getResources()
                .getDrawable(path);
        drawFromPath.setBounds(0, 0,
                drawFromPath.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                drawFromPath.getIntrinsicHeight());
        return drawFromPath;
    }
}, null));
```

How can i achieve this ?

Comment: Is there any reason you are using Html.fromHtml(source, imageGetting, tagHandler)? I would create a layout with an ImageView.

Comment: Text of my TextView field is coming from Strings.xml file where I have used HTML tags for formatting. That is why I have used Html.fromHtml.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create images suitable to all the devices screens sizes and orientations and keep them in corresponding res/drawable folder like drawable-hdpi, drawable-ldpi, etc. Also, create suitable layouts and keep them in corresponding res/layout folders like /layout and /layout-land. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I know this. Can you please let me know some easy way to create images of different sizes from my original image ?